# Python: how to overload reflected numeric operators from C

Tags: python, python-2.7

From python, we can overload operators like so:

```
class X:
    def __add__(self, i):
        return i+3;
    def __radd__(self, i):
        return i+4

x = X()
print x+0  # prints 3
print 0+x  # prints 4
```

If we wish to implement X in a C extension module, we must explicitly register operator overloads. __add__ is doable:

```
X_type.tp_as_number.nb_add = &X_add;
```

But there seems to be no corresponding slot for __radd__. Where is it?

Comment: simple solution: handle both cases in X_add. Sheesh, OP is a moron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different approaches used by Python to handle normal and reverse binary operations. There is the "old style" approach which is supported in all versions of Python 2.x and the "new style" approach which is supported in recent versions (since 2.3 ?). Python 3.x only supports "new style" numeric types.

"old style" numeric types expected operands were already converted to a common type. The nb_coerce slot points to the functions that would convert other numeric types to your custom type.

A "new style" numeric type doesn't use nb_coerce but is expected to check the types of the other operand. With Python 2.x, you need to include Py_TPFLAGS_CHECKTYPES in the tp_flags slot. Nothing special needs to be done with Python 3.

The excerpt is from Python 2.7 abstract.c file:

```
/*
  Calling scheme used for binary operations:

  v     w       Action
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  new   new     w.op(v,w)[*], v.op(v,w), w.op(v,w)
  new   old     v.op(v,w), coerce(v,w), v.op(v,w)
  old   new     w.op(v,w), coerce(v,w), v.op(v,w)
  old   old     coerce(v,w), v.op(v,w)

  [*] only when v->ob_type != w->ob_type && w->ob_type is a subclass of
      v->ob_type

  Legend:
  -------
  * new == new style number
  * old == old style number
  * Action indicates the order in which operations are tried until either
    a valid result is produced or an error occurs.

 */
```

Since Python 3.x only supports "new style" numeric types, only the first calling scheme is used. And since the "new style" can be used with Python 2.7, I normally use the new style.

Comment: Good answer! Also, PEP 208 is relevant.